# is possible to remove previous alert view?

Tags: ios, uialertview

i have create two **UIAlertView** views in one method. Code like below

```
-(void) alert{
UIAlertView *alert_1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@“Alert 1” delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert_1 show];

UIAlertView *alert_2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@“Alert 2” delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert_2 show];
}
```

after call this method. iPhone app will appear popup for 2 times.

first appear is **alert_1**, disappear **alert_1** and appear **alert_2**

after user press ok button in **alert_2** thn appear **alert_1**

should be remove **alert_1** when appear **alert_2**

is possible to remove previous alert view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *alert_1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@“Alert 1” delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert_1 show];
[alert_1 dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
UIAlertView *alert_2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@“Alert 2” delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert_2 show];
```

Answer (score 4):

Send message `- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated` to alert1.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what your requirement is. But from what I understood you want alert_2 to popup first and when clicked on the "OK" button you want to dismiss that alert view and popup alert_1

```
- (void) alertview
{
    alert_1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert 1" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert_1 setTag:1];
    alert_1.delegate = self;

    alert_2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert 2" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert_2 setTag:2];
    alert_2.delegate = self;
    [alert_2 show];
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if (alertView.tag ==2)
   {
    [alert_1 show];
   }
}
```

Please note to declare your alert views in your .h file

Comment: if alertvView delegate is nil. Should be remove preview alertview(alert_1). issue fixed from KudoCC.

Comment: okay.. i am still not clear about the issue you were facing. but i am glad you found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Get UIAlertView by its tag or @Property and use this `[myAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];`